# How do I place the zeros at the top of list and 1's in the last?

Tags: python, list

I have written a code that takes place the zeros at the top of list and 1's at the end of it , but it increases the space and time complexity . How can I reduce the complexity of code.

**Code:**

```
array = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
new_list = []
new_list1 = []
for i in array:
    if i == 0:
        new_list.append(i)
    else:
        new_list1.append(i)

print(new_list + new_list1)
```

Comment: You can use `sorted([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0])` for this

Comment: I cannot use any pre defined function

Comment: Well what are u allowed to use then ? Can you use count ?

Comment: yes we can use it

Comment: @Rabi please accept an answer if it helps you out. Thanks in advance

Comment: ok i accept it and also give me vote of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output needs to be
`[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]`

you can do the following:

```py
In [17]: 
array = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
print([0] * array.count(0) + [1] * array.count(1))


Out[17]: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modifying your code:

```py
array = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
new_list = []
for i in array:
    if i == 0:
        new_list.append(i)
new_list.extend(1 for _ in range(len(array) - len(new_list)))
print(new_list)
```

Prints:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Can you also tell me that if I want to count the number of 0's which is between 1 like two zeros are in this [1,0,1,0,1]

Answer (score 0):

An other way without count and keeping the loops could be that:

```
array = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
new_list = []

for val in array:
    if val == 1:
        new_list.append(1)
    else:
        new_list.insert(0, 0)

>> [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

with sum (in case you are allowed to use `sum`, not clear from the question )

```
array = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
n_ones = sum(array)
new_array = [0 for _ in range(len(array) - n_ones)] + [1 for _ in range(n_ones)]
```

**Remark on booleans**
In python booleans are considered *numeric types* so you can do arithmetic as well. Working only with 0 and 1 as integers, so **more structured data** than boolean `True` and `False`, could give raise to performance "lack".

Notice also that python considers both boolean states as *literals*!

boolean approach

```
array = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
n_ones = len([True for _ in array if bool(_)])
new_array = [0 for _ in range(len(array) - n_ones)] + [1 for _ in range(n_ones)]
```